# Custom section headings

Tags: sectioning

I want to write a report, where each chapter has the same structure. e.g. the first section is always pros, the second is cons, the third is opinions and the fourth section is the final conclusion. Currently, I'm using the following pattern:

```
\chapter{Report title}
\section{Pros}
pros here
\section{Cons}
cons here
\section{Opinions}
opinions here
\section{Conclusion}
conclusion here
```

I have to repeat this pattern for every report.

Is there a way to customise the document such that the first section of a chapter always says "Pros", second "Cons", etc?

So I can just do:

```
\chapter{Report title}
\section{}
pros here
\section{}
cons here
\section{}
opinions here
\section{}
conclusion here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rizhiy Is this Ok?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\newcommand\pros{\section*{Pros}}
\newcommand\cons{\section*{Cons}}
\newcommand\opinion{\section*{Opinions}}
\newcommand\conclusion{\section*{Conclusion}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Report title}

\pros
pros here
\cons
cons here

\opinion
opinions here

\conclusion
conclusion here

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to automate things such that a single `\nextsection` would automatically print Pros/Cons/Opinions/Conclusion according to the value of `\thesection`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the following does as you'd like; the idea is to copy the definition of the original `\section` command, and then redefine the `section` command depending upon the value of the `section` counter.

I've set up values for Pros (1), Cons (2), Opinions (3), Conclusions (4), and then to use the second argument of `\section` as default. This approach also allows you to pass an optional first argument for the `toc`, as demonstrated.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}

\let\oldsection\section

\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{%
    \ifcase\value{section}
    \def\mystring{Pros}
    \or
    \def\mystring{Cons}
    \or
    \def\mystring{Opinions}
    \or
    \def\mystring{Conclusions}
    \else
    \def\mystring{#2}
    \fi
    % if #1 is empty, use \mystring in the toc
    \ifx\\#1\\
    \oldsection[\mystring]{\mystring}
    \else
    % otherwise use #1
    \oldsection[#1]{\mystring}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Report title}
\section{}
pros here
\section{}
cons here
\section[something else for the toc]{}
opinions here
\section{}
conclusion here
\section{}
other
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If every chapter will have four sections and each section should be titled Pros, Cons, Opinions, Conclusions then you could automate things with a single command which prints a command according to the value of `\thesection` counter (as long as `\thesection` is less than four, otherwise it does nothing, maybe it should be made to throw an error or similar if `\thesection` has value four or greater).

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand\nextsection{
    \ifnum\value{section}=3\section{Conclusions}\fi
    \ifnum\value{section}=2\section{Opinions}\fi
    \ifnum\value{section}=1\section{Cons}\fi
    \ifnum\value{section}=0\section{Pros}\fi
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Report Title}
\nextsection
Pros
\nextsection
Cons
\nextsection
Opinions
\nextsection
Conclusions
\end{document}
```

[image]

Although I suspect it may be better practise to manually enter the `\section` commands with appropriate argument as it's less likely to lead to an accidentally mis-named section.